# KnowckoutJS Dynamic load simpleGrid columns upon click button

Tags: knockout.js

All the examples are binding the json data to simpleGrid at the page.load event, which will fire to calculate the column and display gridview. But in my case, the initial load of page won't show the gridview, and upon click on a button which use ajax to return a dataset, then bind to the simpleGrid. Here is the sample

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/FB6LA/).

I tried to have subscribe on the observableArray but that didn't work neither to re-generate the grid, any hints? Thanks!

```
function viewModel() {
var self = this;
self.queryResult = ko.observableArray();
self.update = function (data) {
    //this is an ajax call and return dateset back
    $.each(initialData, function (index, item) {
        self.queryResult.push(item);
    });
};
self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: self.queryResult,
    pageSize: 10
});

}
```

Comment: I am getting error cannot read property viewmodel of undefined. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FB6LA/8/

Answer (score 0):

You never defined any headers in your simple grid. I added like below

```
   self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
   data: self.queryResult,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales ", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB6LA/35/)